# Matsubara sum for particle number

Tags: fermions, thermal-field-theory

I am trying to derive the electron number equation for some thermal system. There is something wrong in my calculation.

The action has the following form:

$S = \sum_{k,n \in \rm{odd}} \bar{\psi}[-\imath \omega_n+k^2-\mu] \psi$

If I calculate the partition function, and then the free energy I get 
$F=-\frac{1}{V}\sum_{k} \ln[ \cosh (\beta (k^2-\mu))]$
and 
Particle number $N=-\partial_\mu F$ is

$N=\frac{1}{V}\sum_k \tanh(\beta (k^2-\mu))$

This diverges, and also occupation number is incorrect.

Instead of this, I can directly evaluate the derivative before calculating the Free energy, in which case I get

$N=\frac{1}{\beta V}\sum_k\sum_{n\in{\rm odd}}\frac{1}{-\imath\omega_{n}+k^{2}-\mu}$

I can resum things to get

$N\propto\sum_k\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\in{\rm odd}}\frac{1}{-\imath\omega_{n}+k^{2}-\mu}+\frac{1}{\imath\omega_{n}+k^{2}-\mu}=\sum_k\sum_{n\in{\rm odd}}\frac{k^2-\mu}{(-\imath\omega_{n}+k^{2}-\mu)(\imath\omega_{n}+k^{2}-\mu)}
$

In which case I directly get

$N\propto \sum_k \tanh (\beta (k^2-\mu))$

Again, I get the incorrect result.

How do I do the summations in such a way that the particle number for the non-ineracting electrons comes out correctly when I take the derivative with respect to the chemical potential ?

1) I can guess where the problem is. It could be related to the resummation.

2) I also understand that there is a simpler correct way to calculate this, which is to use the Green's function with correct limits and interpret that as the particle number. For example, following the ideas emphasized in Eqn-3.144 of these notes. http://www.physique.usherbrooke.ca/tremblay/cours/phy-892/jouvence.pdf

3) I am more interested in clarifying my concepts - finding out where I am going wrong in the approach I described above.

Comment: Could you please mention how you obtained the free energy from the action?